# RC ignored - Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd, dbmail

I have an example query that I am purposely failing as the db and table doesn't exist as part of my test

```
declare @nsql nvarchar(4000)
,@rc int
set @rc = 0
set @nsql = '
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@subject = ''test sub''
,@recipients = ''joe.bloggs@myemail.com''
,@copy_recipients=''null''
,@blind_copy_recipients=''null''
,@body=''test body''
,@Query = ''select * from mydb..tlist'' ,@query_result_header =0 
'
begin try
exec @RC = sp_ExecuteSQL @NSQL
end try
begin catch
    set @RC=@@ERROR
end catch

print @rc
```

**On my SQL2008 server I get this response**

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
RC:14661

**On my SQL2014 server I get this response**

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.
RC:0

My query/issue is why on SQL2014 am I getting a 0 RC?
Its not recognising the failure?